# How to change the email of the root user in GitLab?

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

I'm new in Gitlab. Great project, by the way!

I installed the Gitlab 6.6.5 in Ubuntu 12.04 by [GitLab packages](https://www.gitlab.com/downloads/) locally and everything is working fine.

I changed the information of the root user, but when I try to change the email, Gitlab said that sent a email confirmation to the new email. But, because is locally, it was not able to send this email. There is no postfix or other email server installed.

So, there is some way to change this email of the root user?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily send emails using your email account, I use a dedicated gmail account to send emails, just follow this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/xavierjurado/3138813